# Is there an easy way to tell if a class/struct has no data members?

Tags: c++, class, struct, size, member

Hallo,

is there some easy way in C++ to tell (in compile-time) if a class/struct has no data members?

E.g. `struct T{};`

My first thought was to compare `sizeof(T)==0`, but this always seems to be at least 1.

The obvious answer would be to just look at the code, but I would like to switch on this.

Comment: would you qualify a v-table as a data member? It is a sort-of hidden one.

Comment: `sizeof(T) == 0` seems to exist in D, but is prohibited by the C++ standard, correct.

Comment: Curious why you want to do this?

Comment: @CashCow: Not necessarily, as far as I see it that is an implementation detail.

Comment: Why not just use a regular expression to find these?

Comment: @C Johnson: It would be nice to be able to switch on it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since C++11, you can use the [`std::is_empty` trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_empty).

If you are on paleo-compiler diet, you can use the [Boost.TypeTraits implementation of `is_empty`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_empty.html). It relies on [empty base optimisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo), which is performed by all mainstream C++ Compilers, and ensures that an empty base class will take up zero space in a derived class.

The Boost.TypeTraits implementation uses a helper class which is derived from the class the user wants to test, and which is of a fixed, known size. A rough outline of the logic is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_empty {
    struct helper : T { int x; };
    static bool const VALUE = sizeof(helper) == sizeof(int);
};
```

However, beware that the actual Boost implementation is more complex since it needs to account for virtual functions (all mainstream C++ compilers implement classes with virtual functions by adding an invisible data member for the [virtual function table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) to the class). The above is therefore *not sufficient* to implement `is_empty` correctly!

Comment: Will not work. As  CashCow  says this will not work for classes with virtual function.

Comment: @Ashot: That should not be "will not work" so much as "will not work given some definitions of empty".

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan ... but the solution can be modified by deriving from some base helper class with dummy virtual function as welll as from the class being tested

Comment: @GMan question is "has no data members". So answer is not clear. Your one are more clear IMHO :)

Comment: Ok, I should have made this clear: **don’t** use this metafunction, it’s for illustration purpose only. Use the Boost implementation, it’s much more robust and sophisticated!

Comment: This does work in the sense that it returns true for each empty class. However, if the result is false, the struct may or may not be empty, so "not `is_empty`" does not mean "is not empty".

Comment: To @Konrad Rudolph.  @user396672 is right, you can check is_polymorphic<T>()&& sizeof(T)==sizeof(some_polymorphic_class). This will work  for polymorphic classes on most compilers. It will not work only for classes with multiple inheritance (maybe also for classes with virtual bases).

Comment: Actually I like the **direct** instruction (i.e. not to use the example) from your comment enough to think it should be edited into the answer.

Comment: @Spencer Agreed. Done.

Answer (score 12):

If your compiler supports this aspect of C++0x, you can use `std::is_empty` from `<type_traits>`.

It's specification is:

> `T` is a class type, but not a union type, with no non-static data members other than bit-fields of length 0, no virtual member functions, no virtual base classes, and no base class `B` for which `is_empty<B>::value` is `false`.

I don't think there's a standard way to find if a class is empty with regards to polymorphism.

Comment: how I already commented in Konrad Rudolph answer, it is possible to check if class is empty when it is polymorphic. You need to check `is_polymorphic<T>()&& sizeof(T)==sizeof(some_polymorphic_class)`. This will work for polymorphic classes on most compilers. It will not work only for classes with multiple inheritance .

Comment: @Ashot: "on most compilers" I usually try not to think in terms of compilers. :)

Answer (score 3):

Stepping on Konrad's answer, this handles classes with or without virtual functions.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_empty {
    struct empty_ { virtual ~empty_(); };
    struct helper_ : T { virtual ~helper_(); };
    static bool const EMPTY = sizeof(helper_) == sizeof(empty_);
};
```

Comment: Ok, but the pointer to virtual table is not necessary sizeof(void*) (it seemes wrong, for instance, for 16-bit Borland C++ wich uses 2 bytes "short" pointer for this purpose regardless to memory model). It is better to compare with sizeof(SomeEmptyPolimorphicClass)

Answer (score -2):

The most simple answer to this that both works and is standard complaint:  Look at the header files for the class/struct and its class hierarchy.  They will tell you if there are data elements (as well as a vtable).