# Can we detect empty classes in C++03?

Tags: c++, templates, empty-class, c++03

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to tell if a class/struct has no data members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828992/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tell-if-a-class-struct-has-no-data-members)

Can we detect emply classes, possibly using template?

```
struct A {};
struct B { char c;};

std::cout << is_empty<A>::value; //should print 0
std::cout << is_empty<B>::value; //should print 1

//this is important, the alleged duplicate doesn't deal with this case!
std::cout << is_empty<int>::value; //should print 0
```

Only C++03 only, not C++0x!

Comment: Duplicate-ish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828992/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tell-if-a-class-struct-has-no-data-members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your compiler supports the empty base class optimization, yes.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_empty
{
    struct test : T { char c; };
    enum { value = sizeof (test) == sizeof (char) };
};

template <>
struct is_empty<int>
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};
```

Better:

```
#include  <boost/type_traits/is_fundamental.hpp>
template <bool fund, typename T>
struct is_empty_helper
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template <typename T>
struct is_empty_helper<false, T>
{
    struct test : T { char c; };
    enum { value = sizeof (test) == sizeof (char) };
};

template<typename T>
struct is_empty
{
    enum { value = is_empty_helper<boost::is_fundamental<T>::value, T>::value };
};
```

Comment: @Ben: See the edit which makes your solution slightly incorrect!

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm entitled to edit my answer for each change to the question.

Comment: @Nawaz: Just add a specialization which returns false if `T` is not a class-type.

Comment: @Ben: Sure. That is why I informed you. :-)

Comment: @Ben: Your edit would work with `int` only, how about `double` for example?

Comment: @Nawaz: Not exactly rocket-science to generalize it.

Comment: @GMan: Hmm. I Agree. I think the rest I can do myself. Thanks. +1.

Comment: @Nawaz: There are a strictly limited number of built-in types...

Comment: @Ben: Ish. Compilers can introduce their own types as extensions (`long long`, for example), and it's nice if this kind of thing works with them too where possible. I suspect it would take compiler-specific code to guarantee catching them all, but you could maybe do something with `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized` to filter out extended numeric types before resorting to `is_empty_helper`?

Comment: @Steve: Maybe by using boost like so?