# how to see if an object is blank or not?

Tags: c++, typeinfo

For example,

```
class A {};      // This is blank
class B {int i}; // This is not.
```

How to know if a class or a class's object is blank or not?

Comment: What is your definition of blank ? what about inner class, typedef, friend declaration ?

Comment: How would you tell if an integer is blank?  The value of zero may be valid?

Answer (score 1):

You need what is called "reflection". reflection is the ability to inspect a type for its methods, member etc. The "usual" kind of reflection is not possible in C++, however there are ways to do it.

I suggest you read this answer here:

[How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

or this one:

[Is there an easy way to tell if a class/struct has no data members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828992/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tell-if-a-class-struct-has-no-data-members)

Comment: I don't think reflection is the right word. It is called meta-programming. Reflection is more about query type information at runtime.

Comment: @BryanChen http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3814.html -- the feature of being able to examine the contents of C++ types at compile time is being called "compile time reflection".  This is appropriate, because as a feature it lets you also implement run-time reflection (by using compile-time reflection, then metaprogram a run-time reflection system).