# Determine if class has no (either directly or inherited) non-static data members?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

It's kind of like `std::is_empty` but allows virtual functions,
and the class may also have multiple base classes. This is the hard part. When the class has none or only one base, I can check `std::is_polymorphic` and compare its size with an empty polymorphic class. I have no clue how to do it when it has multiple empty polymorphic base classes.

Comment: You might want to link to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828992) as it covers a lot of the potential solutions for this question. You should also take a look at it if you haven't already.

Comment: What goes wrong with the multiple base case?  Can you show code?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont `struct A { virtual ~A() = default; };`
`struct B { virtual ~B() = default; };`
`struct C : public A, public B {};` Both B and C match the requirement but they may have different size

Comment: Please add all relevant details to the question, not as comments.